# Globally disallow NuGet restore as side effect of other dotnet commands in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

TLDR: How do I enforce that *no* `dotnet` command in my yml pipeline is allowed to restore NuGet packages unless explicitly told to do so? To ensure only the explicit NuGet restore (and corresponding `Cache@2` task) get to do restores?

---

I'm enabling NuGet package locks and caching in my Azure DevOps build pipelines based on [this blogpost by Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/enable-repeatable-package-restores-using-a-lock-file/). The relevant NuGet steps become this:

```yml
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'NuGet Tool Installation'

- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0
  displayName: 'NuGet feed(s) Authentication'

- task: Cache@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Cache'
  inputs:
    key: 'nuget | "$(Agent.OS)" | **/packages.lock.json'
    path: '$(NUGET_PACKAGES)'
    cacheHitVar: 'CACHE_RESTORED'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet Restore'
  condition: ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, true)
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
```

This all works well, I've generated `package.lock.json` by setting `RestorePackagesWithLockFile` to `true` in all of my `.csproj` files, and committed those to version control.

The problem now is that I have dozens of `task`s like these:

```yml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build API'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'Northwind.Foo/Northwind.Foo.csproj'
    arguments: '-c Release'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test Foo'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: 'Northwind.Foo.Tests/Northwind.Foo.Tests.csproj'
    testRunTitle: 'Foo-Tests'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Test Bar dependency'
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: 'Northwind.Bar.Tests/Northwind.Bar.Tests.csproj'
    testRunTitle: 'Bar-Tests'

# etc. etc.
```

All those `dotnet build` and `dotnet test` commands will `restore` packages also when needed. Heck, they might even by side effect *update* the `package.lock.json` or so I presume because Azure DevOps tells me on some builds:

```
Resolved to: <redacted>
##[warning]The given cache key has changed in its resolved value between restore and save steps;
original key: <redacted>
modifiedkey: <redacted>
```

I know from [the `dotnet build` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) that I can use `--no-restore` flag, but then (a) I have to repeat that for all 10ish `dotnet` tasks multiplied against 10 yml files, and (b) have to remember to do so in all future cases too. Similar story for adding `--locked-mode` to *all* commands, I suppose?

Is there a more global way, at the least once per yml file, to prevent any `dotnet` command from restoring by side effect, and instead respect the existing packages from the earlier restore commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was already in linked blog post. There are two *different* csproj properties you can set:

- `RestorePackagesWithLockFile`: "If this property is set, NuGet restore will generate a lock file – packages.lock.json file at the project root directory."
- `RestoreLockedMode`: "If locked mode is set, restore will either get the exact packages as listed in the lock file or fail if it cannot."

So you should use the first option to have lock files *generated* for your projects. Use the second one in CI/CD to ensure that it uses locked mode. No need to force it with `locked-mode`.